# Can you embed Docusaurus inside a larger ReactJS project?

Tags: reactjs, docusaurus

I have a ReactJS web application project, with an auth flow, dashboard, etc. However, I would also like to have a public "Guide" section of the site. To speed development time, I would like to create that Guide/Docs section with Docusaurus. Does anyone know how to integrate a Docusaurus project inside a larger ReactJS app (with one entrypoint - no subdomain, no separate run, etc.). Specifically, I would like to boot up the whole app with `react-scripts start`, not `docusaurus start`. I have not been able to find a solution on the Docusaurus documentation, etc., so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks for your help in advance!